# Google php api list of people who also authenticated the site

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

is there a way to get all your google+ friends who also authenticated my site without any activity logs from my site?

i know the collection of google have 2 parameters only

```
connected and visible
$plus->people->listPeople('me', 'connected', array());
```

connected - is show people who has the activity(with the site authenticated) on their google+.

while visible - is show your circles.

by using connected,do i really need to add a moment/activity on their google+ just to find out they uses my site?

suggestions will be more likely! thanks.

Comment: See if [this](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/listByActivity) link helps.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks for the reply but thats not what i mean. im signing in using google api and im not making an activity. i want to show all my friends who also uses mysite using their google+.

Comment: However, you have to store their mail on registering/accepting, than compare those mails with full list of g+ friends.